# Composer not creating correct sub folders for Symfony component

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Banging my head for hours here -- I'm sure I've forgotten something stupid.

I had a *previously working* Symfony component (Finder). I composer-updated after moving other components to dev in the composer.json file.  **The composer update no longer places the Finder files in the correct subfolder** as it correctly did previously:

```
\vendor\symfony\finder\Symfony\Component\Finder  (correct)
```

Instead, it's putting them into:

```
\vendor\symfony\finder     (incorrect)
```

Unfortunately, most of the file pointers and autoloaders still point to the longer path (use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;)

Here is the composer.json:

```
{
 "require" : {
    "symfony/finder" : "~2.6" // have tried with "2.7.1" 
 },
 "require-dev" : {
    "raveren/kint" : "v0.9",
    "filp/whoops" : "~1.0"
 }
}
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the place where the finder is put is correct. It changed in Symfony, they threw out that whole bunch of useless directory levels that were empty.

Your code should not be affected by this transition. It would only be affected if it tried to include the file that was moved directly. Why would you want to do this - autoloading would solve it for you.

I don't think Composer would write incorrect autoloader files, but to be sure you can run `composer dump-autoload` to recreate them.

Comment: LOL lotta banging my head for nothing ;)  Thanks @Sven.  I'll have to go back and find where I've got some pointer in code for 'use xxx;' that shouldn't be in there.  Agree its better without the useless folders for sure... but wish they had done this originally, as it is breaking something on unix server (not Windows ironically).  Thanks again.

Comment: You misunderstood my answer: The code itself didn't change, the finder classes all are named the same. Only the file location changed. If this breaks your code, you should find out why.

Comment: No, I understood, and appreciated your answer Sven.  Had to go back and hunt through everything.  took all day, and turns out the answer was in a file rename from Upper to Lower case.  Ok by Win, not by Linux.  End of the day, as you said, not an issue with composer or symfony - both of those did their jobs perfectly.